# Geting post information by taxonomy term name

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

How can i get post id from taxonomy term name?

Taxonomy is : post_tag
post_type is : videos
and i have the term name to use to get posts

i tried

```
$args = query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'videos',
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'terms' => $term_name,
            'field' => 'name'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What is the input and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: input is a video tag like "#spot" stored in $term_name, and stored in the db under wp_terms under "name" column, and at the end i need the post id of that video/post to who the tag belongs

Comment: You need to include some more of the relevant code and markup to help your question make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few issues with your current code:

1. Regarding your usage of `query_posts`, "*This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes*" ([source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)). Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), instead.
2. You are assigning your `query_posts` data to a variable named `$args`, but it will actually return posts - not arguments - so that's confusing (bad practice).

Here is a solution using get_posts:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'videos',

  'tax_query' => array(
    array( // note: tax_query contains an array of arrays. this is not a typo.
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $term_name,
    ),
  ),
);

// Collect an array of posts which are given the "post_tag" which includes $term_name
$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) {
  // Display the first post ID:
  echo $posts[0]->ID;

  // Display all posts with "ID: Title" format
  foreach( $posts as $the_post ) {
    echo $the_post->ID . ': ' . $the_post->post_title . '<br>';
  }
}
```